# canvas on android

Tags: android, graphics

I'm new to android graphics and in the process of understanding the graphics subsystem I've read many documents available on net.

One thing that still confuses me is that there is a canvas API that is used for 2d drawing. According the the documentations available, it uses the skia internally to draw.

Now, is this canvas different from the canvas that is returned by surfaces during redraw? For example, if there is a `GLsurfaceview` which has 3d rendering, will it use the 2d canvas API to draw on canvas and eventually on surface ?

Answer (score 0):

Canvas and OpenGL are separate APIs. Canvas does not utitlize OpenGL afaik. And OpenGL has its own lower level functions to handle 2D stuff. In fact you can do 2D using Open GL as well.

Comment: you're right .I understand that canvas api is different from OpenGL API . While i use openGL api , i make use of Glsurfaceview for it . When in need to redraw the glsurfaceview , i'll get a canvas for it . What is this canvas ? unable to decipher the two .

Comment: Is it that the canvas api draws on a canvas using skia . same way opengl es renders 3d ,which when finally transformed into 2d (for display) uses the same redraw mechanism that canvas api uses to draw to canvas using skia ??

Comment: No I dont think thats right. Canvas is this one - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html . And OpenGL has these set of classes - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/package-summary.html . There is the GLSurfaceView class there, but I don't see a Canvas class inside the Open GL ES API.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong ..The Glsurfaceview class further inherits the android.view.SurfaceView , which uses a canvas .

Comment: Just found out from further reading that surfaceview uses canvas but GLsurfaceview uses opengl . Thanks for help !